# Это грубая ошибка - "постпозиция после"?

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

> О частице "себе" словари единодушно утверждают: она употребляется в
>   постпозиции только после местоимений и глаголов, никогда - после
>   наречий.

А как исправить, сохранив термин "постпозиция"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
О частице "себе" словари единодушно утверждают: она употребляется
в постпозиции только после местоимений и глаголов, никогда - после наречий.
```

Не вижу криминала такого соседства именно в научном тексте. Конечно, возможно обойтись и без него:

*О частице "себе" словари единодушно утверждают: она употребляется в постпозиции только по отношению к местоимениям и глаголам, никогда не употребляется после наречий.*

Но в приведённом Вами предложении  речевой ошибки нет,  к тому же сглаживает ситуацию избыточности выделительная частица *только*. Если мы даже заменим *пост* на *после*, это будет возможно:

*О частице "себе" словари единодушно утверждают: она употребляется в позиции "после" только после местоимений и глаголов, никогда - после наречий.* Такие примеры встречаются в научной литературе довольно часто, вот, например:

*Дейктическое значение, присущее указательным прилагательным, усиливается в постпозиции после существительного с определенным артиклем* http://sofiyalorenzzo.narod.ru/Spain/Lengua/mestoim.htm

Как видите, никакого криминала.

Comment: Люсенька, большое спасибо! А было бы выходом их положения - это меня кагбэ осенило - поставить запятую после етой "постпозиции": ***О частице "себе" словари единодушно утверждают: она употребляется в постпозиции, только после местоимений и глаголов, никогда - после наречий.***

Comment: Тогда смысл изменится: она употребляется в постпозиции(вообще), НО только... Получается как бы присоединение или пояснение, а это уже что-то разговорное, не научное.

Comment: Да, пусть "вообще"! Да, пусть уточнение! Низя?..

Comment: В учебнике нельзя, на форуме можно

Answer (score 0):

Грубая ли это ошибка - не знаю. Для непрофессиональной речи, быть может, и сошло. Но тут-то текст явно ориентированный на лингвистов. У них принято *"постпозиция/препозиция чего [частицы] к чему [местоимению, глаголу, наречию]".*

Вот пример из "Корпусной грамматики".

> ... в первых двух случаях деепричастие может стоять как в препозиции,
>   так и в постпозиции к главной клаузе,...

http://rusgram.ru/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5

***...употребляется в постпозиции только к местоимению и глаголу, никогда - к наречию.***

(здесь, похоже, правильно единственное число, хотя не уверен)

или, избегая некоторой вычурности предыдущего:

***...употребляется в постпозиции только с местоимениями и глаголами, никогда - с наречиями.***

Второй вариант не совсем профессиональный (имхо), но всё лучше исходного.

Или уж тогда "позиция после".